# When is the size and shape of an asteroid determined?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

While I was working on an asteroid capture mission, I reverted and retried the launch of my craft many times. I noticed that the mass of the asteroid seemed to be different each time I got to it. It was definitely the same asteroid each time (I was reverting to a saved game in which I was already tracking the asteroid, and its orbit was always the same).

This leads me to believe that the size and shape of the asteroid might be determined neither when it first appears in the tracking station as an unknown object nor when you start tracking it. When are these properties determined? Is it when the asteroid actually comes into view of an owned craft (or other object) for the first time?

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question here given that you tested it in the same way that (short of a dev response) is the only way we could determine this!

Comment: Not gonna do an answer since I'm just speculating here, but I imagine that until you physically are in range to see it in space, the asteroid exists only as an actual programming object as somewhat of a memory saver type thing to not have to phys-simulate things not being seen (smaller than planets) more than the normal orbiting. That said, I fail to see why they would calculate all this stuff based upon the mass of the roid if they're determining when you see it.

Comment: [related](/questions/162755/when-is-the-orbit-of-an-asteroid-determined)